# Learning using layers and CoreAnimation for iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, core-animation

Except for the official docs, what is a good resource for learning how to use CALayers and Core Animation efficiently/correctly?

Answer (score 4):

Beyond Apple's documentation, I highly recommend Marcus Zarra and Matt Long's book "[Core Animation: Simplified Animation Techniques for Mac and iPhone Development](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0321617754)", as well as Bill Dudney's "[Core Animation for Mac OS X and the iPhone](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/bdcora/core-animation-for-mac-os-x-and-the-iphone)".  If you had to pick just one right now, I'd go with the former, which is newer, contains more information on iPhone-specific issues, and is beautifully illustrated.

There are always the [core-animation tagged questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core-animation?sort=votes) here on Stack Overflow, which include many interesting answers on the use of layers and animations.

I've compiled what I know about Core Animation in the detailed class notes for the course I teach on iPhone development.  Those notes can be downloaded from [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/AdvancediPhoneApps.zip) (in [VoodooPad](http://flyingmeat.com/voodoopad/voodoopadlite.html) format).  EDIT (6/29/2010): The video for the corresponding Core Animation session is available with the rest of the class [on iTunes U](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/advanced-iphone-development-spring-2010/id407243032).  I provide many examples of the use of layers and complex animations, including sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it targets Mac OS X (CALayer on iPhone and Mac OS X are close), you can learn a lot of things with the following links:

- http://theocacao.com/document.page/527
- http://theocacao.com/document.page/555
- http://www.claireware.com/blog_files/iphone_animation_view_with_sound.html

For the rest, Google is your friend.